# How do I fix my current scrolled position (view) in Android webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am new to Android programming (classic starting sentence, right!) and hoping someone could guide me. I have been playing with `webview`. I have a webpage: https://weather.com/?Goto=Redirected. Using the following code, I managed to show the above webpage in a `webview` and scrolled down to my desired location (the image with the title "Weather today across the country" on the webpage).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://weather.com/?Goto=Redirected");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    }

    // Enable scrolling
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            int XPos = webView.getScrollX();
            Log.v("Scroll", "XPos = " + XPos);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Now, I would like to "fix" (or maintain) this scrolled position all the time so that `webview` automatically jumps down to this position each time this activity is fired. How can I achieve this? I would highly appreciate if someone could suggest on this. Also, will this position be maintained on orientation change or I would need to tweak the code a bit further?

Comment: You wouldn't really want to do that-  you don't own weather.com.  They can change their UI at any time.  The position will change with every minor tweak to their UI.  Also, it will be different depending on a dozen device settings such as text size and screen size.  If this is a learning app, you can just save it to shared preferences and read in shared preferences in onCreate.  But if this is a release app, that's not a good way to do it.

Comment: @GabeSechan: Thanks for the comment. You are right, I don't own weather.com. But, I have an internal webpage that I know wouldn't change and I need to do the same, scroll down (or zoom) to the specific figure to only show it. Yes, it's a learning thing, could you please elaborate on this, "you can just save it to the shared preferences..."?